# Typescript: different result using function and its code using typeof operator

Tags: typescript, runtime, typescript2.0, typeof

Having this code it produces an error:

```
interface something {
    [id: string]: string | something;
}
let obj: something = {
    '1': 'str',
    '2': {
        '3': 'str'
    }
}; 
function isObject(obj: any): boolean {
    return typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null;
}

for (let key in obj) {
    const specific = obj[key];

    if (isObject(specific)) {
        for (let id in specific) {
            //         ^^^// The right-hand side of a 
            // 'for...in' statement must be of type 'any',
            // an object type or a type parameter 
        }
    }
}
```

However, it's working fine when using function code instead of it `isObject(specific)`:

```
if (typeof specific === 'object' && specific !== null) {
// ...
```

Why? Should I start removing functions in my code?

Comment: `isObject` might tell *you* that something is a non-null object, but *it doesn't tell the compiler*. See "user-defined type guards" in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `if` statement with the function code, TypeScript compiler in the `if` statement block can understand from the condition that the type of the `specific` is `object`. So why it works

If you want to use *function checking*, you can write the return type something like `obj is object`. This will return `boolean` according to your condition and also tell the compiler that your `obj` is `object` or not.

```
function isObject(obj: any): obj is object {
    return typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null;
}
```

For more about this technique you can read [**Typescript Advanced Types**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: So, in my case it's gonna be `isObject(obj: any): obj is object {` ?

Comment: @Alex Yes. Like that